# Where can I find unobfuscated version of dash.all.js?

Tags: javascript, media-source

I need to debug DASH player. I used this [tutorial](https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js/wiki). But I need unobfuscated version of dash.all.js, I don't understand where I can take it. I've checked out sources from this github:

https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js

and built dash.all.debug.js, with grunt:

```
.\dist\dash.all.debug.js
```

but this file is not what I need, because it doesn't contain Dash object. So code from wiki doesn't work, I get an error here:

```
new Dash.di.DashContext(); 
VM1213:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: Dash is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanx.

Comment: Why don't you ask using github issue?

Comment: Looks like we don't have a tag for dash-js video player project.

Answer (score 1):

In order to add the dash.js reference implementation to the application, you’ll need to get the dash.all.js file from the 1.0.0 release of dash.js project. You could navigate to the previous releases of dash.js project on github and go to 1.0.0 release. I am including 1.0.0 release dash.js repository here https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js/tree/1.0.0 to make your work easier.